# Creating a wrapper method in C++ at runtime - prototype known

Tags: c++, methods, runtime

I'm currently wrapping around an API that takes function pointers and calls them back at some point. The only issue is that the prototype for this callback function provides a pointer to the state I'm wrapping around instead of my new class. My goal is to hide the original API from the user, so I need a way to dynamically create a method that calls back a different function whose prototype is instead my new class. Here's a simplified code visualisation.

```
struct Old_API
{
    public:
        typedef int (*OldCallback)(Old_API*);
        void RegisterCallback(OldCallback);
};

class New_API
{
    private:
        Old_API* m_WrappedState;

    public:
        typedef int (*NewCallback)(New_API*);

        New_API() { m_WrappedState = new Old_API; }

        void RegisterCallback(NewCallback func)
        {
            // Pseudocode, obviously won't work
            // This is the actual method that would be called back from Old_API
            // It acts as a buffer to call the "new" format of callbacks
            int CallbackLayer(Old_API* state)
            {
                m_WrappedState = state;
                return func(this);
            }

            m_WrappedState->RegisterCallback(&CallbackLayer);
        }
};

// This is what it would look like in runtime

int SomeCallback(New_API*)
{
    // Code
}

New_API* state;

int main()
{
    state = new New_API;
    state->RegisterCallback(&SomeCallback);

    return 0;
}
```

Specifications

- Must be done at runtime so passing the function pointer as a template parameter won't work.
- Instances of `New_API` are created by the user and are nearly stateless - they simply wrap around arbitrary `Old_API` instances.
- `Old_API` instances are passed to the callback function and don't map to a single `New_API` instance. The "CallbackLayer" method is intended to remove the need for the user to have to setup the state themselves, thus hiding `Old_API`'s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fully wrapping the interface, it makes this easy.

First `New_API` registers its own listener on `Old_API`, using whatever means `Old_API` offers to associate the callback with that instance of `New_API` (could just be a field in `Old_API`, or if that's not available, even something like a static `unordered_map<Old_API*, New_API*>`).

Then, `New_API` has its own system for registering listeners. (You're showing function pointers here, but that's C thinking... at worst, you should have something which takes a `std::function`.)

When `New_API` gets its notification, it simply notifies its own listener(s) in turn. There's no direct mapping between listeners: `Old_API` will have exactly one listener, regardless of how many listeners are on `New_API`.

Comment: Here's the kicker I should have mentioned:  I cannot change the structure of Old_API, and for every function I pass to New_API a function must be passed to Old_API. I also cannot map instances since there are multiple Old_API instances - New_API has to work pretty much stateless.

Comment: I don't understand. If a particular `Old_API` doesn't map to a particular `New_API`, how exactly would you like to decide which `New_API` to pass to your wrapped callback?

Comment: `New_API` instances are setup by the user. `Old_API` instances are provided by the unmodified callback - the user will ideally never have to see them. I did create one in the example code just for simplicity's sake, but in practice, this won't happen. I added some additional specifications to the OP that should clarify this.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Each ``RegisterCallback`` call binds a ``New_API`` instance to the passed function pointer. See ``CallbackLayer``'s "this" usage.